# How to run Svelte app inside existing docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, svelte

I am using https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp and my localhost runs inside docker.
I want to run svelte app inside the docker. How to add that svelte app container in my docker.yml file

I entered php container and inside the project executed- npm run dev.
Terminal says project started but on browser it does not work

Comment: Show us your *docker.yaml* file as well as your entire setup.